# Seeking data source for index constituents and changes

Tags: programming, index, indexes

I need to find a definitive list of US and UK index constituents. I'm currently monitoring S&P100, S&P500, DJIA, FTSE100, FTSE350 etc. and curating the list manually, which is causing problems. M&A, delisting, renames events are causing my code to go astray.

I've had a look at Intrinio and Quandl and cannot see an obvious candidate. A HTTP REST API would be ideal but flexible enough to implement most things.

Comment: Are you willing to settle for ETFs or do you need actual indices' constituents? The former is much easier and cheaper to get and you leverage the fact that fund managers pay and are paid to track the index.

Comment: @DavidAddison the actual constituents is preferred but cost always is a factor. Will look into the ETF option.

Comment: The best way to do this could depend on whether you need constituents weights. For the S&P indices, the weights of each constituent will be exactly proportional to the dollar value of its public float. Also, if you were able to gain access to a major academic/institutional data-feed (Big 4 include S&P Capital IQ, Bloomberg, FactSet, Reuters), this data should be pretty easy to get.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at Algoseek.com. They have the ETFs and the components of the Indices. Their dataset is "as is", it is what you would have received from the exchanges. But they track and keep separate set for the publicly published index changes.